# How to set variable name as a string? c++

Tags: c++

```
std::string VariableName = "name";
int (VariableNameHere) = 5;
```

From my understanding of c++ what I am asking is most likely impossible. If it is please post possible alternative solutions. Thanks!

Comment: It's possible with macros but the name still must be known at compile time.

Comment: You could use a `std::unordered_map<string, int>` and then do `mymap[VariableName] = 5;`

Comment: Alternatively `#define VariableName name` and then `int VariableName = 5;`, which relies on the preprocessor.  But, since I abhor the preprocessor, please don't do that.

Comment: Solutions to *what?* What are you actually trying to accomplish with this approach? Why do you need a variable whose name is defined in another variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have it is not possible, you would need to have some kind of look-up system, such as:

```
std::map<std::string, int> variables;
...
variables["name"] = 5;
```

Comment: Using regular data structures rather than variables with special, *magical* names is always better.